# How to check memory usage of all static objects in a c#.net application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have loads of static object in my application.
Want to check the memory usage of all static object , whether they are efficient to lie inside the memory from the time application is created (in mean once the application pool starts or its restarted)

don't want to use any of the tools or exe's , want to have my own Lib to check

Edit Post : 
Need some simple way in the code , by which I would be able to trace the memory usage of static methods , members. 
Using these parameters I would be able manage profiler / monitor for my system

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "static objects" - there's no such concept in .NET. There are "objects which are only referenced by static variables for most of the time" - is that what you mean?

Comment: @jon: Static object I refer to as ,all static classes, static methods and members

Comment: But those aren't *objects* at all. What would the memory usage of a static method be, when it's not being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use a profile because it is impossible to do is at runtime and bear in mind that the size of an actual object doesn't include the size of any objects it references.

A quick tip (but not accurate) could be to Serialize the object and check the buffer length which should stick to the object size